# Return list of files that were modified in a particular folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

How can i get a list of all changes from TFS that were in a particular folder?

Say my application code is layed out like:

```
/myapp/
/myapp/admin/...
/myapp/section1/...
/myapp/section2/...
```

How can i get a list of all changes that occurred in the folder `section1` ?

I want a list of files that were changed from within that folder, and the changeset # and be able to see a compare on the file ideally.

Comment: In Visual Studio or writing your own App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Source Control Explorer.
2. Navigate to the folder you want pending changes for.
3. Right-click on the folder and select "View Pending Changes".

If you would like a comparison for all changed files, repeat the process above, except select "Compare" instead of "View Pending Changes".